# CircularFifoBuffer crashing after initializing on android app

Tags: java, android, collections, structure

Tested and it Works on a non android program but immediately crashes after initializing on Android. Log cat isn't producing any error messages either. I found this from [CircularFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html).

Any obvious problems?

**Edit:** I do get this error message if I add in the jar files into the libs folder (not externally) and then add it to build path. This error isn't present though, if I add the jar files externally.

> [2012-08-05 20:56:03 - wifiCollection] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.apache.commons.collections.SequencedHashMap$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

**Edit2**:

> 08-05 21:12:48.837: I//system/bin/batteryd(1189): 1566474 v_bat 3.678 (3.677), i_supply 0.500, i_demand 0.282 => v_bat_idle 3.649 (3.649), level 41% (41%, 41%), state 5
>
> 08-05 21:12:50.837: I//system/bin/batteryd(1189): 1568477 v_bat 3.678 (3.677), i_supply 0.500, i_demand 0.282 => v_bat_idle 3.649 (3.649), level 41% (41%, 41%), state 5
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.267: I/ActivityManager(1291): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection/.WiFiLocationApp bnds=[245,418][355,553] }
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.337: I/dalvikvm(1374): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.353: I/ActivityManager(1291): Start proc com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection for activity com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection/.WiFiLocationApp: pid=1782 uid=10045 gids={1015}
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.634: D/dalvikvm(1782): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1571 objects / 198264 bytes in 56ms
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.751: V/LocationManagerService(1291): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{45a6e008 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@45a6e4b8}
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.774: V/Tagging(1782): Application starting
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.774: V/Tagging(1782): Checking for wifi
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.774: V/Tagging(1782): Creating new wifiMode
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.782: E/dalvikvm(1782): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer', referenced from method com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.782: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 575 (Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;) in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.782: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0032
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.782: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: dead code 0x0034-0041 in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;. (Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp;)V
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: I/dalvikvm(1782): Could not find method org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer.isFull, referenced from method com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.detectStableEnvironment
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3504: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;.isFull ()Z
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0006
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0230 in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;.detectStableEnvironment ()Z
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: I/dalvikvm(1782): Could not find method org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer.size, referenced from method com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.match
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3506: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;.size ()I
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x000f
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: dead code 0x0012-0227 in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;.match ()Z
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: I/dalvikvm(1782): Could not find method org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer.add, referenced from method com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.processResults
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3502: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;.add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0020
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: dead code 0x0023-0050 in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;.processResults ()V
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.790: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: dead code 0x0074-00f0 in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;.processResults ()V
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: I/dalvikvm(1782): Could not find method org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer.iterator, referenced from method com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.takeAverage
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3505: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;.iterator ()Ljava/util/Iterator;
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x001b
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: D/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: dead code 0x001e-0419 in Lcom/jimmyc/summer/wificollection/WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode;.takeAverage (Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;)Ljava/util/Map;
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: W/dalvikvm(1782): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer;)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: V/Tagging(1782): Starting WiFi mode
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.798: D/AndroidRuntime(1782): Shutting down VM
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: W/dalvikvm(1782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d8a8)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.(WiFiLocationApp.java:182)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp.onResume(WiFiLocationApp.java:1272)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1782):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 08-05 21:12:51.814: W/ActivityManager(1291):   Force finishing activity com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection/.WiFiLocationApp
>
> 08-05 21:12:52.009: D/dalvikvm(1291): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11331 objects / 567768 bytes in 76ms
>
> 08-05 21:12:52.314: W/ActivityManager(1291): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{457131f0 com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection/.WiFiLocationApp}
>
> 08-05 21:12:52.314: D/Sensors(1291): using MMA7660FC Accelerometer (name=MMA7660FC Accelerometer)
>
> 08-05 21:12:52.321: D/Sensors(1291): get_orientation portait device
>
> 08-05 21:12:52.431: V/LocationManagerService(1291): _requestLocationUpdates: listener = Receiver{45711848 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@45a461c8}
>
> 08-05 21:12:52.840: I//system/bin/batteryd(1189): 1570480 v_bat 3.678 (3.677), i_supply 0.500, i_demand 0.282 => v_bat_idle 3.649 (3.649), level 41% (41%, 41%), state 5

```
public class test () {
    CircularFifoBuffer f1 = null;
    CircularFifoBuffer f2 = null;

    public test () {
        Log.v (TAG, "Starting...");
        try {
            f1 =  new CircularFifoBuffer(4);
            f2 = new CircularFifoBuffer(4);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v (TAG, "Error: " +e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you adding CircularFifoBuffer into Android?

Comment: it's imported as an external jar in the same why I imported statistics libraries from apache. Is there something special I have to do for android

Comment: Can you post you logcat output? I assume you are seeing the "Starting.." mesg in your logcat but not the "Error: " mesg?

Comment: This is true, how can I get useful logcat? I only know how to get the ones I filter out. Other than that, there are other messages (many of which are part of the normal runtime messages)

Comment: If your are using eclipse: open the logcat view, clear any existing output (paper with red cross icon), run your app, then click on a single entry, press ctrl-a to select all lines and then click the floppy disk icon to save all selected entries to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logcat output, it looks like the class is not being included in your apk:

```
08-05 21:12:51.782: E/dalvikvm(1782): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer', referenced from method com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.WiFiLocationApp$wifiMode.<init>
```

Add would say your best bet would be to get the source, include it in your project and have it recompiled in your build environment.

Comment: When its compiled, the compiler (ecj in Eclipse or the javac that ships with your JDK) has no issue with *linking* your code with the classes in the jar file, but its the Davlik VM that is having issues (not being able to load the Apache class), it could be because of the way the dex tool is cross-compiling the class file bytecode into its own bytecode.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I still get the error message from Edit1, but I think that can be removed with some digging. At least it's compiling and not crashing.

Comment: Happy to help, please mark the answer as accepted if you feel it solved the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

Check for jar dependencies of your libraries. You may be missing something. (Doubtful as you say you've tested it outside of Android).

You may need to build from source to get it to work as the jar may be built with a different version of Java (Android supports Java 6 not 7).